# Handling args and kwargs Ruby 3.0 and 3.1 with Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-3, ruby-3.1

I am doing an upgrade from Ruby 3.0.6 to Ruby 3.2.2 on our project, and I ahve encountered a weird issue that I tried to understand for past few days.
We are using RSpec for tests and in one of the tests we have this code:

```rb
    let(:request) { FactoryBot.build(:custom_request) }

    context "when not requesting their data" do
      let(:mail) { CustomtMailer.request_email(request: request) }

      it "renders the headers" do
        #expect something
      end
    end
```

and CustomMailer class looks like this:

```rb
class CustomMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  layout "application_mailer"

 
  def request_email(request:, csv: nil)
    #some data processing

    recipients = request.email
    sender = request.sender
    subject = "Some subject"

    mail(to: recipients, subject: subject, from: sender)
  end
```

Well, the first problem I have with existing code is that while the request_email is an instance method, it is being called as class method in whole project, and somehow it works???
Second problem is the tests used to pass with Ruby 2.7.8 and Ruby 3.0.6. But after Ruby 3.1 tests are failing, and I get this error:

`ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0; required keyword: request)`

My first idea was to make the method a class method, since it doesn't use any instance variables, but then I get the problem with the mail function
`NoMethodError: undefined method 'mail' for CustomMailer:Class`

But the most troubling thing is that the call to the `request_email` method doesn't fail, and when I tried debugging and inspected how the params were passed, I saw that all arguments were passed as positional arguments, and are a part of args object, and not kwargs object.
Any ideas why it was working before, and how to fix this?

Comment: ActionMailer does some pretty funky metaprogramming to delegate class method calls to instances of the mailer class. While this might be suprising it's completely in line with the documentation. https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html

Comment: Probably just a typo in the question, but the test references `CustomtMailer` and the class is actually `CustomMailer`.

Comment: No idea how it worked before and not now. But, I wonder if switching to positional args in the `request_email` method would solve the problem.

Comment: Typo is only in the question, since I had to change the real names, NDA bla bla bla.
My suspicion is due to autosplatting changes in 3.1, but still didn't get it properly.
Changing to positional arguments works, but in that case I have to add a check for nils and change the calls in the rest of the app.
My 2nd suspicion was it may be an ActionMailer issue since the rails 6.0 is older than ruby 3.1, so those changes could be fixed in later versions, but it is not working in rails 6.1 also, still trying to find a way to fix this without using positional arguments or creating a custom wrapper

Comment: @NedimRamic Were you able to get a solution to this issue?
I am also facing same issue. kwargs are not working well with Mailer methods.

Comment: @AnandBait Sorry for late response, I have added the answer to how I solved it

Answer (score 2):

A lot of time passed, but someone reminded me of this question, and I'm posting a solution now. The way I solved the issue was I moved from
`CustomtMailer.request_email(request: request)` to
`CustomtMailer.with(request: request).request_email`

and in the mailer class, instead of calling keyword argument

```
def request_email(request:)
    # ...
    req = request
    # ...
  end
```

I gett request value like this

```
def request_email
   # ...
   req = params.fetch(:request)
   # ...
```